# Unable to activate themes on localhost

Tags: plugins, themes, errors

I have a fresh install of WordPress and I am unable to activate themes that I have installed from zip files.

When trying to activate the theme the page takes minutes loading and then the entire WP site crashes (admin panel too). I have tried different themes.

Themes that are installed directly  from the WordPress theme store on the admin panel work fine.

I have tried increasing the memory on **php.ini** file but still it doesn't solve the issue.

I also tried changing WordPress versions(upgrade and downgrade) , deactivated plugins, but the result is the same.

I am using:
**Ubuntu 16.04
PHP 7**

Comment: add these lines at the end of wp-config.php `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` if it's already there, change it to true and see what errors are showing up

Comment: @Vishwa this line already exists but the only error I get after the long load is a error 500

Comment: try adding these lines right below it `ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

Comment: @Vishwa added the lines you said and I keep getting the same error 500

Comment: it's not intended to fix error but to see what are the errors. what you see?

Comment: @Vishwa oh yes that's what I mean I still get the same "Error 500" screen after minutes of loading. No specific code error is displayed.

Comment: open your dev tools by ctrl+shift+i and select console tab to see if there's any errors. then network tab. then reload the page. select your homepage address and click on it. then it'll open info area. check Params and Headers

Comment: @Vishwa tried to do what you said still no error was displayed. After trying different things I am starting to think that it's an issue with the database(I am not sure tho) I guess slow queries.